# Looking for a partial converse of Rolle's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, derivatives, soft-question, continuity

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R $ be a continuous function differentiable in $(a,b)$ such that $f(b)=0$ and for some $c \in (a,b) , f'(c)=0$ ; then under what additional conditions can we conclude that $\exists d \in [a,c) $ such that $f(d)=0$ ? ( I am kind of trying to go in reverse direction of Rolle's theorem ...)

Comment: I doubt anything useful can be found: at most, we will obtain a very narrow class of functions tailored specifically for one case.

Comment: what about f(a)

Comment: you are not exactly fullfiling the required conditions in reverse

Comment: @ADG : Actually I thought demanding $f(a)=0$ would be too much ; so I kept myself content with just one root anywhere between $a$ and $c$ ; but if you can say something about $f(a)$ with certainty ; I would be delighted

Comment: I think you cannot find any useful condition but something like $f(a)=0$, because your $f$ can do anything near $c$.
Maybe your question should be like so: If there is some $c$ such that $f'(c)=0$, under which additional assumptions can we find $a,b$ with $a<c<b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$? This were some kind of reverse to Rolle (and is not so difficult to answer :) )